# Post Entire HTML Document in Code Review Without Editing First

Tags: support, design, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

This question has been asked and answered before.  But some of the answers are outdated, and some don't work, and the only one that does, well, I'm hoping it's not the only option.

How can I post an entire html document into Code Review (an SE member site) without modifying the code before posting?

I want to post an entire html document into Code Review for reviewing.  Here are the methods mentioned in other posts:

- **Use the '010 101' button.**  - This appears not to be available anymore.
- **Wrap in backticks.** - This has unusual behaviour.  Everything before the first `<div>` tag inside the `<body>` appears in the post as normal text, not as html code.  Everything after that is rendered as I wish, as html code.
- **Wrap the code in an `<html>` block.** - This has almost identical behaviour to the backticks.
- **Wrap in a `<pre><code>` block.** - This works.  But it requires that I first replace every `<` with `&lt;`.  I will do that, but I just want to be sure I haven't missed an option that will let me paste without modifying.

Comment: Do you have a question? Or an issue that needs addressing? This is just a nice story so far, but nothing actionable.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post.

Comment: What does *entire document* mean? It is discouraged to post long code segments.

Comment: It's actually for the Code Review site, where it is in some cases encouraged to post more rather than less.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: Anything that the FAQ [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) does not explain?

Comment: That one didn't come up when I searched.  I found a lot of posts, that gave me the four methods I mention in my question, but not the `{}` option.  Voting to close as duplicate.  (That should earn me some kind of obscure badge, voting to close own question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **010 101** button is now **{}**, which has the same action as the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd>, which is to indent the selected block 4 spaces, marking it as code.

That's how you would do it.

However, there is normally no need to post an *entire* HTML document - just posting the *relevant* sections should do (and a link to a working jsFiddle can only help).

Comment: It's for Code Review.  I should have said that instead of SE, but I wasn't sure people would know what it was.  And it's only about 40 lines.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick - Fair enough. It doesn't matter if it is a whole document or a few lines of code - both cases are served by the same action, namely the above options.